# Split a vector of numbers into bounded subsets

Tags: r

Say I have a vector `c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)` which I want to split into subsets bounded by another vector `c(4, 6, 11)`.

I want the result to be three vectors `[1,2,3]`, `[4,5]`, and `[6,7,8,9,10]`. (Or `[1,2,3,4]`, etc... I'm not picky.)

Is there a simple way to do this in R without resorting to some funkiness with `factor` or `apply`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `findInterval` and `split`:

```
> x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
> split(x, findInterval(x, c(4, 6, 11)))
$`0`
[1] 1 2 3

$`1`
[1] 4 5

$`2`
[1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

I don't know if this falls under "resorting to some funkiness" or not though.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what I was looking for. I posted my own solution below, but it seems you were faster.

Answer (score 0):

I found this way of doing it:

```
> x <- c(1:10)
> bounds <- c( 3, 7, 12)
> f <- cut(x, c(0, bounds))
> split(x, f)
$`(0,3]`
[1] 1 2 3

$`(3,7]`
[1] 4 5 6 7

$`(7,12]`
[1]  8  9 10
```

but Ananda's is much cleaner.

However, I think this allows you to specify `right=false` in `cut`, to change the behaviour.